# Modifying Array Elements from Separate Functions

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I know I've seen several very similar questions posted here, but I can't seem to make sense out of them or apply their solutions to my code to get the desired result.

I'm trying to modify an array acting as a stack from my pop() and push() functions. It's apparent that functions can read arrays that you pass to them, but they can't change the values of the actual array that's declared in my main function. So it's more like the function is acting on a kind of copy of the array you give it in main. (correct me if I'm wrong please)

I got tired of changing about 14 lines in my code every time I wanted to try a new pointer trick I found on the internet, so I made a very simple program that I can easily modify until I get the result I want.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//supposedly changes the 3rd element of the array from 2 to 3
int modifyArray(int *arr[], int len)
{
    printf("changing 2 to 3\n");
    arr[3] = 3;
    return 0;
}

//desired output: 0, 1, 3, 3, 4
//current output: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    modifyArray(arr, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've seen a lot of solutions on the internet that use some malloc() function which I don't understand at all (hence I can't seem to get it to compile when I try to use it) and all of the other methods I've tried either won't compile due to incompatible data types or throw a memory access exception.

Any help would appreciated

Comment: write other number than 3, also change `int modifyArray(int *arr[], int len)` to `int modifyArray(int *arr, int len)`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a sufficient answer but currently, I don't think you need to use malloc() in main. In your modifyArray() though, understand that you are receiving the address of the starting point of your array. Thus, arr in modifyArray() is a pointer to a pointer (the name of the array).

Try`(*arr)[3]=3;` instead of your original code. Plus, I think you might already know this but I'll remind you that since array indexes begin with 0, arr[3] refer to the fourth element of the array.

Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

converting comment to answer:

array index always starts from zero, so that way you are over writing the element at pos 3 with same element, so you dont see any change.

do the below changes to your code.

write other number than 3 in `modifyArray` , `arr[3] = 8;` and also change `int modifyArray(int *arr[], int len)`  to `int modifyArray(int *arr, int len)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little error in your code syntax. While taking parameter in your function you are declaring like `int *arr[]` but it should be only `*` or `[]` there. You should write like `int modifyArray( int *arr, int len )` or `int modifyArray( int arr[], int len )`.

You should be getting a warning while running your code.

I think this should work!